# Jquery: Explanation about this pattern

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can someone please explain in what cases the following syntax can be used and how does this work?

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.hoverIntent = function(f,g) {
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Thanks!

Comment: The question is about the jquery object being passed..

Comment: Ok, I reopened as I chose the wrong duplicate. What you have there is a self-invoking function.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I believe the question is about the fact that "jQuery" is passed as an argument, with the formal parameter having the name "$".

Comment: yes that's the question

Comment: You should be able to read more about that function [here](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-ui-modal-form-dialog-has-input-that-does-not-allow-type). Just `ctrl+f` for 'function($)'. It provides some clarity.

Comment: @Rookie it's just insurance - it allows the code inside the anonymous function to refer to the global jQuery object as "$" even if the global "$" is not really jQuery. Of course, the technique doesn't do you any good if the global "jQuery" symbol *also* isn't jQuery.

Comment: Note that the self-invoking function is redundant here anyway, as `jQuery` is provided as a parameter to the document ready handler function by default.

Comment: thanks guys for the comments, i will refer to the links provided!

Comment: The marked duplicate is a terrible choice for this question, because the answer for practical purposes is "Use this pattern to wrap jQuery code that might choke if you use `jQuery.noConflict()`"